# Can I specify where I want a data extension to be created when using server-side javascript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, dataextensions

the code for creating a DE is straightforward, but I'm trying to specify where I want this to be created rather than the root DE folder.

Is such a thing possible?

thx

Comment: can you provide reference to 'the code for creating a DE'. There are multiple routes available to create a DE in SSJS. If you can specify and perhaps share the code, it would likely allow us to better assist you.

Answer (score 3):

You would just need to add in the `CategoryID` of the folder you wish to push the DE into.

The [SSJS DataExtension Core Library Function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_dataExtensionAdd.htm) operates as a 'short hand' for the [API object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/dataextension.htm) so you should be able to include all the attributes listed there.

I have tested the following code and it has worked correctly and inserted the DE into my specified folder.

```
var deObj = {
        "CustomerKey" : "demoDE",
        "Name" : "My Demo DE",
        "CategoryID" : 8675309, /* Put your folder (CategoryID) here */
        "Fields" : [
          { "Name" : "Field 1", "FieldType" : "Number", "IsPrimaryKey" : true, "IsRequired" : true },
          { "Name" : "Field 2", "FieldType" : "Text", "MaxLength" : 50 },
          { "Name" : "Field 3", "FieldType" : "Date", "Ordinal" : 2 },
        ]
    };

var myDE = DataExtension.Add(deObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using the new WSProxy; according to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_WSProxy_useSSJS.htm), it's more performant than the existing core library methods. Here's an [example from the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_WSProxy_create.htm#example-create-a-single-dataextension-object):

```js
var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

var guid = Platform.Function.GUID();
var name = "my test de - " + guid;

var de = {
    Name: name,
    CustomerKey: guid,
    Description: "Another DE added via SSJS",
    Fields: [{
        FieldType: "Text",
        Name: "ID",
        MaxLength: 36,
        IsPrimaryKey: true,
        IsNillable: false,
        IsRequired: true
    },
    {
        FieldType: "Text",
        Name: "Name",
        MaxLength: 200
    }],
    CategoryID: 101377
}

var res = prox.createItem("DataExtension", de);
```

Where CategoryID is the ID of the target folder.